# Why doesn't 1.fxe4 Nf6 work for black in this puzzle?

Tags: analysis, puzzles

I was solving puzzles and I failed this one.
The correct answer was `fxe4 fxe4 Bxh5+`.
Why can the knight not just move to `f6` and be safe there?

`fxe4 Nf6 exd5 fxd5` is in my opinion more preferable for black.

```
 [Title "1...Nf6?"]
 [fen "rnbqk2r/ppp3pp/3b4/3p1p1n/3Pp3/1P2PPP1/P1P1B2P/RNBQK1NR w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because after `Nf6, e5` is a double attack on the `d6` bishop and the `f6` knight.

The puzzle aside, given that black's dropping the piece anyway, may as well go for something practical, like `Nxg3, hxg3, Bxg3+...` and take 2 pawns for the piece, with some positional compensation as the king will be misplaced, but objectively white should of course be easily winning.

```
 [Title "Puzzle"]
 [fen "rnbqk2r/ppp3pp/3b4/3p1p1n/3Pp3/1P2PPP1/P1P1B2P/RNBQK1NR w KQkq - 0 1"]

 1.fxe4 Nf6 (1...fxe4 2.Bxh5+) (1...Nxg3 2.hxg3 Bxg3+) 2.e5
```

Comment: That Bxg3 line can make things more difficult for black. Though the king has to run to d2, the center is closed and White can make use of an open f-file after 3...fxe4, or large central space gain after 3... dxe4 4. Bh5+ folllowed by an eventual c4.

Comment: With black's two pawns being passers, the game is unclear.  The main problem is that black can't castle after Bh5+.